# CGI- Password from HTML won't print

Tags: html, c, cgi

We were asked to create a twitter-like program using C, HTML, MySQL and CGI. The first step is creating the login page wherein we would ask the user to enter their username and password. I used CGI x HTML in doing that and here are my programs:

HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action='/cgi-bin/password .cgi'>
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" ><br>
    Password: <input type="password" name ="password" id="password"  maxlength="10">
    <input type ="submit" value='Submit'>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

CGI:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{

char *data;
char *token;
printf("Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n");
printf("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Is Your Password and username this?<title></head><body>");
data = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
  if (data) {
        token = strtok(data, "&");
        while (token) {
              while (*token != '=') 
              {
              token++;
              }
          token++;
          token = strtok(NULL, "&");
          }
    printf("The average is %s\n", token);
  }
  printf("</body></html>");
  exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

PROBLEM: After entering the username and password and pressing the submit button, the cgi is not printing anything. It's just blank space. How do I fix this and be able to print what the user enetered in the username and password boxes? Thanks!

Comment: You don't print anything inside the loop where you parse the query-string. And after the loop `token` will be `NULL` (that's part of the loop condition) and you try to print that `NULL` pointer.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Any suggestions as to how do I print the username and password? Should I print strtok(data) then? I'm kinda new to this I'm sorry :((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters I suggest you *copy* the string you get from `getenv`. You should never modify the string you get from `getenv`, and `strtok` modifies it.

Also, when you call `strtok` the pointer you get is pointing to the beginning of the name in the `name=value` pair. By modifying the pointer variable (which you do with `token++`) you lose the start and will not have a pointer to the name anymore.

Then I suggest you look at something like [`strchr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strchr) to simplify the code and don't have the inner loop.

Putting it all together, if it is possible you could do something like

```
char *data_ptr = getenv("QUERY_STRING");
char data[strlen(data_ptr) + 1];  // +1 for the string terminator
strcpy(data, data_ptr);

char *name = strtok(data, "&");
while (name != NULL)
{
    char *value_sep = strchr(name, '=');
    if (value_sep != NULL)
    {
        *value_sep = '\0';
        char *value = ++value_sep;

        printf("Name = %s\r\n", name);
        printf("Value = %s\r\n", value);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Malformed query string\r\n");
    }

    name = strtok(NULL, "&");
}
```

You can [see it in "action" here](http://ideone.com/rLovYk).

Comment: It's still not working. I tried to run this but it compiles with an error so I tried with:

Comment: char *data_ptr= getenv("QUERY_STRING");. It now compiles but it still prints a blank page. Any help? Thanks